# Is it possible to develop Event Receivers for sharepoint 2016 using MS Visual Studio Professional 2012

Tags: development, event-receivers, administration, 2016, visual-studio-2012

I have installed a new version of visual studio 2012 professional. and inside it i am able to create solutions for sharepoint 2010 only, as follow:-

[image]

so can anyone adivce what i need to install to be able to create event reciever for sharepoint 2016 ?

second question now on another environment i have visual stdio with the tools for sharepoint 2013. so now if i have an event receiver which works on SP 2013 will it work on SP 2016 ?? i mean i can develop it using SP 2013 tools and deploy it under SP 2016 ..

Answer (score 3):

To develop Farm Solutions (which would contain event receivers) for SharePoint 2016 you need a machine with SharePoint 2016, Visual Studio 2015, and the [Microsoft Office Developer Tools Preview 2 for Visual Studio 2015](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=51683).

You also asked about developing Farm Solutions in SharePoint 2013 and deploying them to SharePoint 2016. The testing I did suggests that this would work. Of course there could be cases where it won't work so you should test thoroughly if you try this.

See my YouTube video [What's New for Developers in SharePoint 2016](https://youtu.be/DuNzniUKNhc) for more on both subjects.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55856/discussion-on-answer-by-rob-windsor-is-it-possible-to-develop-event-receivers-fo).